# Apply CSS to partial view rendered in HTML email

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-email

I am using a view to create an html email. This view has a partial view passed to it that contains the footer information. Is there a way to apply CSS to the partial view elements? I am using inline CSS to modify the way the other items in the view render in the email, but I am not sure how to modify the elements coming in from the partial view?

Comment: Do you create elements in the partial view?.

Comment: I pass in the name, address, and phone number of a contact person.

Comment: Unfortunately, HTML in email requires inline CSS definition. If you do not create this part you need to accept what you got. However you can try to wrap this part in some element(s) with CSS classes that will make it look better.

Answer (score 0):

So I did not think this through. I applied the inline css to the partial view and it carried through to the email.